# Is it normal for wget to exit with exit code 8 after mirroring?

Tags: wget

I ran this command:

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites  \           
     --no-parent --wait=0.1 --random-wait 'https://www.example.com'
```

It successfully downloaded all the links, and also appeared to successfully convert all the links:

```
Téléchargés : 33 fichiers, 5.2M en 17s (309 KB/s)
...
...
Liens convertis dans 32 fichiers en 0.2 secondes.
```

What's puzzling to me is the exit code; wget exited with an exit code of `8`. Is this normal?

Comment: Were there no errors at all like a broken link causing a bad response?

Comment: @Freddy I see no error messages at all. Everything looks normal.

Comment: According to the `wget` manual, an exit status of 8 means "Server issued an error response."  Are you redirecting the error stream to someplace so that you don't see the server error?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I did not redirect the error stream anywhere. I don't see any server errors either. I managed to download all the files.

Comment: Did you see 404 for an url? I had this issue ;)